# Can I put jquery code in a bunch of pure javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to insert my jquery code into a bunch of javascript code

I want to put the `$ajax` jquery code into  `function getInfo()`   but seem not work.I try to wrap all js code with `document.ready`  but not work too.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: '201637766943985',
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.8'
  });
  FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are connected.';
      document.getElementById('fb_login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not logged in.';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You are not logged into Facebook';
    }
  });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {
    return;
  }
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function fb_login() {
  FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are connected.';
      document.getElementById('fb_login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not logged in.';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You are not logged into Facebook';
    }
  }, {
    scope: 'email'
  });
}
function getInfo() {
  FB.api('/me', 'GET', {
    fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,email'
  }, function(response) {
    ////////call jquery AJAX here/////////////////////
  });
}

function fb_logout() {
  FB.logout(function() {
    document.location.reload();
  });
}
```

Comment: you can put jQuery code within your pure JS code. Only requirement is that you need to add JQuery library via `<script>` tag within `<head>` section of your HTML page.

Comment: jquery **is** javascript

Comment: I know  but how to insert it  in a bunch of javascript code.  I try to insert the $("status").html("Hello <b>world!</b>");  but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `status is an ID` you need to write your jquery as

```
$("#status").html("Hello <b>world!</b>");
```

Selectors in jquery begin with `#` for ids and `.` for classes.

Please refer this simple link to get an idea on how to use selectors

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: No Problem, Glad to help :)